# Django Channels Error - Cannot import BACKEND 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer'

Tags: python, django, redis, django-channels

I have installed Django-Channels but while running the daphne-server I am getting this error given below:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/channels/asgi.py", line 36, in make_backend
"Cannot import BACKEND %r specified for %s" % (self.configs[name]['BACKEND'], name)

channels.asgi.InvalidChannelLayerError: Cannot import BACKEND 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer' specified for default
```

My settings.py is:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
    "CONFIG": {
        "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://X.X.X.X:6379')],
    },
    "ROUTING": "MyProject.routing.channel_routing",
},
}
```

Need help in resolving this error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just needed to install 'asgi_redis'. I was assuming that it would have gotten installed by default while installing Django-Channels, but it doesn't. 'asgiref' gets installed by default and not 'asgi_redis'. So to solve this issue, one can just run:

```
> sudo pip install asgi_redis
```

Comment: I found this to be also true for "Cannot import BACKEND 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer'": pip install channels_redis. Thank you.

Comment: With asgiref-2.3.2 i need to install channel_redis. NOT asgi_redis

Comment: @jlSta, great, this solved one of the issues with new channels 2.x, wish it was written in the docs (and, it's channels_redis)

Comment: I add this as a solution, so

Answer (score 28):

In regard to Utkarsh's reply itt's been renamed to:

```
pip install channels-redis
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @drulang. For anyone trying to install Django Channels 2, the documentation describes the changes that have taken place here - https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/one-to-two.html#channel-layers

Comment: I think it should be `pip install channels_redis`. Worked for me at least...

Answer (score 7):

I also faced same problem while working with django-channels, by following the documentation examples https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html
you just need to install channels-redis as

> pip install channels-redis

to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

With *asgiref-2.3.2* and maybe more, you need to install *channel_redis*.

NOT *asgi_redis*.

```
pip install channel_redis
```

Comment: Yes!  Use this for channels.  I am using channels 2.1.5.  e.g. `pip install channels==2.1.5`   (This version also installs `asgiref==2.3.2`)

Comment: I think it should be channels_redis

Answer (score 4):

Faced the similar issue. Solved it by installing channels_redis:

```
pip install channels_redis
```

Also using channel redis in setting too:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
    },
    'ROUTING': 'ws.routing.application',
}
```

Comment: thanks, `pip install channel_redis` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

That did the thing for me.

```
daphne = "~=3.0.2"
channels = "~=3.0.4"
channels-redis = "~=3.3.1"
async-timeout = "~=3.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case `channels_redis` version 4.2.0 was not compatible. I downgraded it as follows and my code worked:

```
pip install channels_redis==3.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case asgiref version 2.3.2 was not compatible. I downgraded it as follows and then my code worked.

```
pip install asgiref==1.0.0
```

Comment: See comment from jlSta above, e.g. `pip install channel_redis`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, however, I got the same problem and I got the solution from this link:

https://github.com/django/channels_redis/issues/113#issuecomment-405071710

based on **Andrewgodwin** he says:

"**asgi-redis** is an outdated package (the previous version of channels_redis). You can uninstall it to solve this error."

and that worked for me